# Creating a subset in R using a double loop Continuation

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

DF:

Year 1901  1901  1903  1968 1978 2002 2006 2010

species    1      1    2      65   1    82   3   1

lat:  49   46   47    47   48   43.1  44.23  47.11

long:  -79.22 -79.5  -78.22 -79.84 -78.11  -77.114  -76.33  -76.2

Julian_Day: 79  125   165   178   193  68  90  230

Land:   16   24  25  30   34   34  39   41

There are more variables but that's an example of the matrix. I only want to keep the rows for each year AND for each species that has the lowest value for the Julian_day. Ie: the second row would be omitted here, because 79 is less than 125 for species 1 in 1901.

Comment: Can you provide your desire output?

Comment: This might be the data.frame with which we might help? structure(list(Year = c(1901, 1901, 1903, 1968, 1978, 2002, 2006, 
2010), species = c(1, 1, 2, 65, 1, 82, 3, 1), lat = c(49, 46, 
47, 47, 48, 43.1, 44.23, 47.11), long = c(79.22, -79.5, -78.22, 
-79.84, -78.11, -77.114, -76.33, -76.2), Julian_Day = c(79, 125, 
165, 178, 193, 68, 90, 230), Land = c(16, 24, 25, 30, 34, 34, 
39, 41)), .Names = c("Year", "species", "lat", "long", "Julian_Day", 
"Land"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: from this example, my actual data set contains ~120,000 rows and 15 columns, I'd want: 

Year  species    lat   long      Julian _Day   Land
1901   1            49   -79.22     79                16
1903    2            47    -78.22    165              25  
ect...

essentially the output would look identical to the original EXCEPT I would lose the second row of data (the second 1901) because I only want the smallest value for the julian day (the first appearance of that species) for that year.

Comment: DJJ, I'm not sure if you're suggesting that I make a data frame but i'm dealing with a huge amount of data I've imported from excel and just want to eliminate the rows that don't met my conditions. I only want to   keep the rows that have information regarding the smallest julian day value for EACH species for EACH year.

Comment: Try `library(data.table); setDT(df)[ ,.SD[which.min(Julian_Day)],  Year]`

Comment: @John I'm only suggesting that you provide a format easy to work with. It's much easier to paste the data.frame in the format i've posted. You don't have to paste all the data. dput(head(data.frame)) might be enough

Comment: Nice try @DavidArenburg always faster... :), I think it's, library(data.table); setDT(df)[ ,.SD[which.min(Julian_Day)], species]

Comment: I think David's may have worked...Is this a new subset since I didn't name it? like are the changes permanent so that I could now export to R, this new version?

Comment: except I'm still missing the species parameter, I have 83 species that need to be incorporated into the argument

Answer (score 1):

First of all. I would suggest you providing a `data.frame` in a format that is easy for people to use. We'll be able to help you better and faster

```
 df  <- structure(list(Year  = c(1901,  1901, 1903,  1968, 1978,
 2002, 2006, 2010), species = c(1, 1, 2, 65, 1, 82, 3, 1), lat =
 c(49,  46, 47,  47, 48,  43.1, 44.23,  47.11), long  = c(79.22,
 -79.5,  -78.22,   -79.84,  -78.11,  -77.114,   -76.33,  -76.2),
 Julian_Day =  c(79, 125, 165,  178, 193,  68, 90, 230),  Land =
 c(16,   24,   25,   30,   34,    34,   39,   41)),   .Names   =
 c("Year",  "species",  "lat",  "long",  "Julian_Day",  "Land"),
 row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is your data.frame

```
 df
 #   Year species   lat    long Julian_Day Land
 #1: 1901       1 49.00  79.220         79   16
 #2: 1901       1 46.00 -79.500        125   24
 #3: 1903       2 47.00 -78.220        165   25
 #4: 1968      65 47.00 -79.840        178   30
 #5: 1978       1 48.00 -78.110        193   34
 #6: 2002      82 43.10 -77.114         68   34
 #7: 2006       3 44.23 -76.330         90   39
 #8: 2010       1 47.11 -76.200        230   41
```

Generally, you just have to do `dput(head(your dataframe))` But you can build a small fake data frame to illustrate your point if cannot reveal your data.

Her's a possible solution using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ ,.SD[which.min(Julian_Day)], .(species, Year)]
```

Comment: My guess is that they need `setDT(df)[ ,.SD[which.min(Julian_Day)], .(species, Year)]`

Comment: Oh finally I think i'm getting somewhere. I tired the first option above and it worked, except, it's only gave me one observation(row of data) per year, so I only have about a hundred rows since i'm working with 100 year time span, when for each year there's usually at least 4 to 5 species( it really all depends on the year)...if this makes sense, ie for 1901 I should actually have six rows of data because there are six different species observed in that year